# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser find string

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using PHP simple DOM parser but it does not seem to have the functionality to search for text. I need to search for a string and find the parent id for it. Essentially the reverse of normal usage.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadXML($xml);
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$result = $x->evaluate("//text()[contains(.,'617.99')]/ancestor::*/@id");
$unique = null;
for($i = $result->length -1;$i >= 0 && $item = $result->item($i);$i--){
    if($x->query("//*[@id='".addslashes($item->value)."']")->length == 1){
        echo 'Unique ID is '.$item->value."\n";
            $unique = $item->value;
        break;
    }
}
if(is_null($unique)) echo 'no unique ID found';
```

Comment: This is PHP's `DOMDocument`, not the [SimpleHTMLDom Library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) as the OP stated he was using.

Comment: Ack, missed that. Still can't get my head around people using that slow, slow thingamajig, but you're right, this isn't the answer the OP is looking for then.

Comment: I tried this answer... but DOMDocument spat out lots of errors... It seems very picky about the html... but you are right simple html parser is a real memory hog. Is there anyway to get it to play better with poorly formated html?

Comment: Sure there is, before loading, set `$d->recover = true;$d->strictErrorChecking = false;`, and of course, use `loadHTML()` instead of `loadXML()` for HTML. If you still get to much errors, which you cannot ignore (never display errors on production sites), you could set `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` to handle them seperately from other PHP errors.

Comment: Ack, `wrapper` is not what we want :). My bad, my `XPath`  is a bit rusty, try `//text()[contains(.,'617.99')]/parent::*/@id`, seems to work here.

Comment: works a treat... except for the warnings... is there anyway to check if that id is unique?

Comment: Warnings can be disabled by either prepeding `@` (`@$d->loadHTML($html);`, which is kinda evil, or using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);$d->loadHTML($html);libxml_clear_errors();` (preferred IMHO). An id _should_ be unique, but we all know it's sometimes not. You can check with `$x->query("//*[@id='theid']")->length == 1` (for `priceIncTaxSpan3047` it is, but look at the 50 `Table_01`'s, no wonder DOMDocument protests :)

Comment: What I am looking to achieve is if it is not unique then it finds the parents id too and it keeps doing that until it finds a unique selector.... this xpath code is complex! Can you give me one last bit of guidence :)

Comment: Well, just this once :P Edited my answer. I think it can be solved without a loop in 1 XPath query, but gets bit out of scope, and is probably best served with a seperate question with the proper `XPath` tags, so you don't have to rely on rusty ol' me :P

Answer (score 9):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

$eles = $html->find('*');
foreach($eles as $e) {
    if(strpos($e->innertext, 'theString') !== false) {
        echo $e->id;
    }
}
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: `$e->id` is the Simple DOM way to get the ID attribute. Perhaps try changing `$eles = $html->find('*');` to `$eles = $html->find('p, div');` or something.

Comment: is it not getAttribute('id') ... I can't get it to work regardless :S

Answer (score 5):

Just imagine that any tag has a "plaintext" attribute and use standart attribute selectors.

So, HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
  <span>London is the capital</span> of Great Britain
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <span>Washington is the capital</span> of the USA
</div>
```

can be imagined in mind as:

```
<div id="div1" plaintext="London is the capital  of Great Britain">
  <span plaintext="London is the capital ">London is the capital</span> of Great Britain
</div>
<div id="div2" plaintext="Washington is the capital  of the USA">
  <span plaintext="Washington is the capital ">Washington is the capital</span> of the USA
</div>
```

And PHP to resolve your task is just:

```
<?php
  $t = '
    <div id="div1">
      <span>London is the capital</span> of Great Britain
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <span>Washington is the capital</span> of the USA
    </div>';
  $html = str_get_html($t);
  $foo = $html->find('span[plaintext^=London]');
  echo "ID: " . $foo[0]->parent()->id; // div1
?>
```

(take in mind that "plaintext" for `<span>` tags is right-padded with a space symbol; this is default behaviour of Simple HTML DOM, defined by constant `DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT`)

Comment: so far the best answer

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer.  The entire example is a little long but it works.  I also show the output.

The HTML for what we are going to look at:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple HTML DOM - Find Text</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Simple HTML DOM - Find Text</h3>
<div id="first">
 <p>This is a paragraph inside of div 'first'.
   This paragraph does not have the text we are looking for.</p>
 <p>As a matter of fact this div does not have the text we are looking for</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
 <ul>
  <li>This is an unordered list.
  <li id="love1">We are looking for the following word love.
  <li>Does not contain the word.
 </ul>
 <p id="love2">This paragraph which is in div second contains the word love.</p>
</div>
<div id="third">
 <a id="love3" href="goes.nowhere.com">link to love site</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_for_text($iUrl,$iText)
{
echo "iUrl=".$iUrl."<br />";
echo "iText=".$iText."<br />";

    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($iUrl);

    // get text elements
    $aObj = $html->find('text');
    if (count($aObj) > 0)
    {
       echo "<h4>Found ".$iText."</h4>";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<h4>No ".$iText." found"."</h4>";
    }
    foreach ($aObj as $key=>$oLove)
    {
      $plaintext = $oLove->plaintext;
      if (strpos($plaintext,$iText) !== FALSE)
      {
         echo $key.": text=".$plaintext."<br />"
              ."--- parent tag=".$oLove->parent()->tag."<br />"
              ."--- parent id=".$oLove->parent()->id."<br />";
      }
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!

// user_agent header...
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

scraping_for_text("test_text.htm","love");
?>
```

The output:

```
iUrl=test_text.htm
iText=love
Found love
18: text=We are looking for the following word love.
--- parent tag=li
--- parent id=love1
21: text=This paragraph which is in div second contains the word love.
--- parent tag=p
--- parent id=love2
25: text=link to love site
--- parent tag=a
--- parent id=love3
```

That's all they wrote!!!!

Comment: Great example. Would you know how to go from text, back to an element? I want to search by text and then find the nearest element. It's from an old table layout without any classes or IDs.