# PHP SimpleHTMLDomParser + Find lonely string

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using the [SimpleHTMLDomParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to go through a html code and find various things. Everything works fine so far, but there is one problem:

How do I find a string that has no ID, no class and no unique parent element?

In my case, I started with extracting content from a div:

```
$descrs    = $html->find('.show_synopsis');

foreach($descrs as $descr) { 

    echo($descr->innertext);

}
```

This looks like:

```
<div class="show_synopsis">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. <b>Source:</b> LORES.

</div>
```

Now, is it possible find and delete `LORES` from the above example?

Since `LORES` is a variable and can change, I was wondering if its possible to simply always find the word next to `<b>Source:</b>`?

I have tried a few different ways, but none worked so far. I have tried to adapt a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465690/php-simple-html-dom-parser-find-string), but wasnt able to adjust them for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.?)<b>.*Source:.*<\/b>.*\./', '$1', $descr->innertext);
```

Comment: This seems not to work. Although I get no error message, the `<b> Source: </b> LORES` gets "echo´ed" as-well and is still visible in the output!

Comment: You first said `<b>Source:</b>` and then `<b> Source: </b>` (spaces before and after `Source:`); which one is the one you need the replace?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It looks exactly like this: `Random text.<br><br><b>Source: </b>CBS  <br>Random text.`

Comment: I just edited my answer to cover both with and without spaces scenarios. Please try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just replace the LORES in the string you are echo-ing?

```
echo str_replace('LORES', '', $descr->innertext);
```

Comment: Oh yeah :) That seems to work. One last thing: if I use this way and have various strings, would I simply create a for each loop and check each string or is there another (simpler) solution?

Comment: You can replace 'LORES' needle in the replace function with an array of multiple needles.

Comment: Oh and if this matters: the html always looks like this: `<b>Source:</b> LORES` - so would i even be possible to always remove `<b>Source:</b>` and the word (LORES in our example) next to it?

Comment: I have modified my question a bit, but overall your solution works fine - but it would be more comfortable if I could find a way without having to know all possible strings and puting them in an array.

Comment: In this case you could use preg_replace instead of str_replace.

Comment: Could you maybe update your answer with an example? :S I think I am still doing something wrong using `preg_replace` : `Error: Unknown modifier.`